# Login page keeps repeating and making a menu

Tags: python, authentication, menu

Hello I am trying to write a program that asks the user for his username and password. If his username is equal to admin and his password is equal to 123 then the program should print 'You are in'. If the user inputs a wrong answer three times the user gets locked out of the program permanently. The program should first thing view a text file and if it contains the number 0 the program continues off to the login page but if it contains 1 the program ends. The number 1 should be written in the text file if the user input the wrong password three times.

The problem is that the program keeps on looping the input username and password part. How can I fix this please? I also wish to input a menu if the user gets the correct username and password. After which line should I input the menu? Thanks in advance appreciate the help!

```
f=open(r"C:\Users\User\Desktop\Resources\locked.txt","r")
contents = f.read()
if contents == '0':
    username = 'admin'
    password = '123'

attempts = 0
while attempts <3:
    username=input('What is your username?')
    password=input('What is your password?')

if username == 'admin' and password == '123':
        print('You are in')

else:
    attempts+=1
    print('Incorrect username/password')

if attempts==3:
    f=open(r"C:\Users\User\Desktop\Resources\locked.txt","w")
    for line in f.readlines()[1]:
        f.write('\n')
        f.write('1')
        f.close()
        print('Your account is locked...please contact developer')
```

Comment: Is this the real indentation in your code?

Comment: Yes this is the exact code

Comment: The print statement bellow `if username == 'admin' and password == '123':` seem to break indentation. Can you please check?

Comment: The while-loop only requests input but does neither check it nor does it increment `attempts` due to the used indentation.

Comment: So I fixed the indentation and it stopped looping but when moving on to the last part ''' for line in f.readlines()[1]: ''' it says that it's not readable. Did I write it wrong as I don't know the exact code

Comment: When opening a file in `w` mode previous content is deleted and the file is only open for writing.

Comment: I changed my code to this:
'''
       if attempts==3:
            f=open(r"C:\Users\User\Desktop\Resources\locked.txt","r+")
            f.readline(1)
            f.replace('0','1')
            f.close()
            print('Your account is locked...please contact developer')
'''
It is showing me a replace error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are only looking or a 1 or 0 in the file then there is no need to write multiple lines. This should work for you here:

Reformat to allow if 1 automatically stops user.

```
file = open("locked.txt","r")
contents = file.read()
if contents == '0':
    username = 'admin'
    password = '123'
    file.close()
    attempts = 0
    while attempts < 3:
        username=input('What is your username?')
        password=input('What is your password?')
        if username == 'admin' and password == '123':
            print('You are in')
            attempts = 4
        else:
            attempts+=1
            print('Incorrect username/password')
    if attempts==3:
        file = open("locked.txt","w")
        file.write("1")
        file.close()
        print('Your account is locked...please contact developer')
else:
    print('Your account is locked...please contact developer')
file.close()
```

The above will have the output look like this:

```
runfile('D:/ProgrammingSource/Python/PracticeVarious/SO_Question.py', wdir='D:/ProgrammingSource/Python/PracticeVarious')

What is your username?bogus1

What is your password?bogus1
Incorrect username/password

What is your username?bogus2

What is your password?bogus2
Incorrect username/password

What is your username?bogus3

What is your password?bogus3
Incorrect username/password
Your account is locked...please contact developer
```

When you try to run the program again it will say:

```
runfile('D:/ProgrammingSource/Python/PracticeVarious/SO_Question.py', wdir='D:/ProgrammingSource/Python/PracticeVarious')
Your account is locked...please contact developer
```

And until you change the file info from 1 to 0 it will stay locked.

Comment: Thank you that worked. My last problem is that after the 1 is changed in the text file and in python it is printed 'Your account is locked...please contact developer') the program continues to the username anyway. I need to make the program stop if there is a 1 in the file.  I don't know how to print the code here but I did this at the top: f=open(r"C:\Users\User\Desktop\Resources\locked.txt","r") 
contents = f.read()
if contents == '1':
    print("Your account is locked ..please contact developer")

Comment: If you used the code the way I wrote it it should stop after you entered either the write admin pass or you entered wrong 3 times. Can you provide screen shot? Try to copy my code to new file and run. Maybe there is something additional we may be missing.  Also don't forget to up vote and select chosen answer.

Comment: I updated my answer with examples of what the exchange will look like. I ran this code in Spyder and Visual Code both and works fine. You can edit your post to provide additional information or just apply an answer to your post with your additional changes if you need to.  I do not think the comments here allow screenshots, but answers should.

Comment: Absolutely! if anymore problems just ask. Also don't forget that when you get up enough points you are eligible to give up votes to people! Keep enjoying coding it is a lot of fun!